# Template #each & rendering

Tags: templates, meteor

Why does the template get rendered the number of times that correlates with the Each in my template.

```
<template name="carousel">
<div class="pikachoose">
<ul class="carousel" >
{{#each article}}
    <li><a href="#"><img src="{{image}}" width="500" height="250"  alt="picture"/></a><span>{{caption}}</span></li>
{{/each}}
   </ul>
   </div>

</template>

Template.carousel.article = function () {
return News.find({},{limit: 3});

}

Template.carousel.rendered = function() {
//$(".pika-stage").remove();
alert($(".carousel").html());
//$(".carousel").PikaChoose({animationFinished: updateNewsPreview});
}
```

In this case it would alert 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way Meteor handles data updates. Your `article` data function returns a cursor that is to be used in the template. Initially, the cursor is empty, and data is pulled from the server, one article at a time. Each time an article is fetched, the contents of cursor are changed (it now has one more article), and therefore the reactive `article` method causes template to rerender.

---

If you need to be sure that your code runs only once, there are several possibilities depending on what you need.

The easiest one is just to use `created` instead of `rendered`.

If you modify DOM elements, you can also mark elements you modify so that you won't process them twice:

```
Template.carousel.rendered = function() {
    _.each(this.findAll('.class'), function(element){
        if($(element).data('modified')) return;
        $(element).data('modified', true);
        ...
    });
};
```

You can disable reactivity for the cursor, though it's a sad solution:

```
Articles.find(..., {reactive: false});
```

The most invasive, but also the most versatile is to observe when the data is fully loaded:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('articles', {
        ready: function() {
            ...
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may have to do with the use of the `.rendered` callback. Each time the loop runs the DOM is updated so the callback will run again.

When I had this problem in the past, I found it helpful to use Meteor event handlers whenever possible, to eliminate load order issues like this one. In this case, maybe you could try a timeout, so that that the `.remove()` and `.PikaChoose()` calls only run after the DOM has been quiet for a certain interval. Hope that works for you.

Comment: `.rendered` is not the cause of the problem, but an indicator. The issue is a side effect of reactivity. Also, using timeouts to wait for data being fetched is a **terrible** idea.